# python list is being split apart as the letters of the first item instead of reading all items

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is going to be a bit complicated, but ill try my best:

I have a function called `teammate_data()`, which reads through some text files to find data and compile them back into a list. My code looks like this:

```
teammate_data = functions.teammate_data(username)
session['team_name'] = teammate_data[0]
session['teammate_name'] = teammate_data[1]
session['teammate_health'] = teammate_data[2]

print(session['team_name'], session['teammate_name'], session['teammate_health'])
```

`teammate_data` reads as: `['team 1', 'nick', 'dead']`. (This should not be the problem, I have already extensively tested this.) This means that the session variables should split apart the list into individual strings. However, instead, python is returning this: `['t', 'e', 'a']`

Why would Python split the items into the first three letters of "team"?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: u say teammate_data reads as: ['team 1', 'nick', 'dead'], at what point in the code did u do a print statement to confirm this

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that `functions.teammate_data()` is not returning a list as you expected, but a string.

So instead of `['team 1', 'nick', 'dead']`,  you are probably receiving `'team 1, nick, dead'`.

Double check `functions.teammate_data()` and see if that's the case.

Comment: This was my first assumption, but I’ve already checked it. It does return a list. :( I can add a link to the relevant code on GitHub if needed

Comment: Could you please? I'd be happy to take a look.

Comment: If `teammate_data()` is indeed returning a list, than its content could be `['t', 'e', 'a']`. Can you check that?

Comment: here: https://github.com/CT-42210/senior-assasin-system

Comment: The code I referenced above is in app/routes, the code that generates the list is in functions. You might have to clone the entire thing for it to correctly generate the data

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: one of my old pip installs has a function called `teammate_data()`, and it was calling that instead of my own.